# C++ do/while loop and calling functions?

Tags: c++, loops, methods, do-while

I am having trouble trying to get this program to loop if user enter 'y' they'd like to continue.  I'm super new to programming by the way so any help is greatly appreciated.  I figured the best was to add a do/while in main and as k the user if they'd like to continue at the end of the code but, I quickly realized that wouldn't work unless I called the previous methods for user input and output.  That's where the issue is arising.

Thanks again for any help!

```
/* 

 • Ask the user if they want to enter the data again (y/n).
 • If ’n’, then the program ends, otherwise it should clear the student class object and
 repeat the loop (ask the user to enter new data...).

 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student {
    public:
    Student();
    ~Student();
    void InputData();       // Input all data from user
    void OutputData();      // Output class list to console
    void ResetClasses();        // Reset class list
    Student& operator =(const Student& rightSide);  // Assignment operator

private:
    string name;
    int numClasses;
    string *classList;
};


//array intialized to NULL
Student::Student() {
    numClasses = 0;
    classList = NULL;
    name = "";
}

//Frees up any memory of array
Student::~Student() {

if(classList != NULL) {
    delete [] classList;
}
}

// This method deletes the class list
// ======================
void Student::ResetClasses() {
    if(classList != NULL) {
        delete [ ] classList;
        classList = NULL;
}
numClasses = 0;
}



//inputs all data from user (i.e. number of classes)
//using an array to store classes
void Student::InputData() {
 int i;

// Resets the class list in case the method
// was called again and array wasn't cleared
ResetClasses();

cout << "Enter student name." << endl;
getline(cin, name);
cout << "Enter number of classes." << endl;
cin >> numClasses;
cin.ignore(2,'\n');   // Discard extra newline
if (numClasses > 0) {
    //array to hold number of classes
    classList = new string[numClasses];
    // Loops through # of classes, inputting name of each into array
    for (i=0; i<numClasses; i++) {
        cout << "Enter name of class " << (i+1) << endl;
        getline(cin, classList[i]);
    }
}
cout << endl;
}

// This method outputs the data entered by the user.
void Student::OutputData() {

int i;
cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
cout << "Number of classes: " << numClasses << endl;
for (i=0; i<numClasses; i++) {
    cout << "  Class " << (i+1) << ":" << classList[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
}


/*This method copies a new classlist to target of assignment.  If the operator isn't overloaded       there would be two references to the same class list.*/
Student& Student::operator =(const Student& rightSide) {

int i;
// Erases the list of classes
ResetClasses();
name = rightSide.name;
numClasses = rightSide.numClasses;

// Copies the list of classes
if (numClasses > 0) {
    classList = new string[numClasses];
    for (i=0; i<numClasses; i++) {
        classList[i] = rightSide.classList[i];
    }
}
return *this;
}

//main function
int main() {
    char choice;
do {
// Test our code with two student classes
Student s1, s2;

s1.InputData();     // Input data for student 1
cout << "Student 1's data:" << endl;
s1.OutputData();        // Output data for student 1

cout << endl;

s2 = s1;
cout << "Student 2's data after assignment from student 1:" << endl;
s2.OutputData();        // Should output same data as for student 1

s1.ResetClasses();
cout << "Student 1's data after reset:" << endl;
s1.OutputData();        // Should have no classes

cout << "Student 2's data, should still have original classes:" << endl;
s2.OutputData();        // Should still have original classes

cout << endl;
cout << "Would you like to continue? y/n" << endl;
cin >> choice;
if(choice == 'y') {

    void InputData();       // Input all data from user
    void OutputData();      // Output class list to console
    void ResetClasses();        // Reset class list
}
} while(choice == 'y');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you make classlist `vector<string>` then you no longer need to delete it or make an assignment operator or copy constructor (which you forgot). It just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of

```
if(choice == 'y') {

    void InputData();       // Input all data from user
    void OutputData();      // Output class list to console
    void ResetClasses();        // Reset class list
}
```

Because the variables `s1` and `s2` are inside the do-while loop, they'll be recreated on each iteration.  (The constructor will be called at the definition, and the destructor will be called at the closing brace of the loop, before it tests `choice == 'y'` and repeats).

The other problem you run into is that your standard input isn't in a state compatible with calling `s1.InputData()` again.  Because you just used the `>>` extraction operator to read `choice`, parsing stopped at the first whitespace, and there is (at least) a newline leftover in the buffer.  When `Student::InputData` calls `getline`, it will find that newline still in the buffer and not wait for additional input.

This is the same reason you used `cin.ignore` after reading `numClasses`.  You'll want to do the same here.

Comment: These are not "variables"; they are function declarations. It's likely the OP intended to call functions with the same name from the global scope, rather than redeclaring similar local ones. I fail to see what removing this entire conditional block will achieve.

Comment: Yeah that won't help because it will re-run the program without asking the user input again.  I've tried calling the input and output functions different ways with no luck.  Any hints or ideas?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please take your comment away.  Those are not the variables, but I never said they were.  I said the variables ARE inside the loop.  Well, they are.  Your comment has totally missed the point.  If you fail to see what removing the conditional block will do... did you even look at the code in the question?

Comment: @user3862586: When it starts from the top of the loop again, it will create the variables `s1` and `s2` afresh, and then immediately call `s1.InputData()`.  Why do you think that will not ask for user input again?

Comment: I know the original poster is new, but man... that is one convoluted piece of code.

Comment: That's how I had it at first and it would loop around again but it would just print "enter student name" and skip to "enter the number of classes", I couldn't figure out why it is skipping that first user input?

Comment: @user3862586: Because after `cin >> choice;` the input buffer has a leftover newline character?  Looks like you already ran into and solved that problem with `cin >> numClasses;`

Comment: It's a project for school and we have to do stupid overloading functions and stuff like that.   Is that what you're talking about or is my code in general that bad?  I've literally only had 5 one hour classes so far on c++ and virtually zero other programming experience.

Comment: @user3862586 In general it's not bad at all, I think you're doing really well.

Comment: @user3862586: No, `ResetClasses` isn't doing anything with `cin` at all.  It's the `cin.ignore(2, '\n');` part making it work after `cin >> numClasses;`   You need that after `cin >> choice;`, too

Comment: Never mind I see what you are saying!  Thanks Ben Voigt, that answered my uestion!  If you post that comment in an answer I will select it

Comment: Sorry no this is still not a good answer. Uncharacteristic. I'm just being honest.

Comment: Why what's wrong with it?   He answered my question and it is working the way I want it too.  Also, I haven't heard any help from you, just criticism of other people that are trying to help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you want to offer criticism, go ahead.  But your original comment was attacking a strawman; I never said the things you said were wrong.